# Memory and CPU Utilization of an Oracle Query

Tags: oracle

Assuming I execute a query like the one below in Oracle;

```
SELECT t1.check_in,t1.check_out, t1.room_id,t2.room_name 
FROM mydb.reservation_tb as t1
LEFT JOIN mydb.rooms_tb as t2 on t1.room_id = t2.room_id
WHERE t1.check_in = '2012-08-01' and t1.check_out = '2012-08-08' and t1.room_id = 12
```

I want to know if there is a way I can determine the amount of Memory and CPU time that were utilized by this query when it executed in ORACLE.

Comment: Look at V$sqlarea

Comment: If you're running the query yourself, the easiest way is probably autotrace.

Answer (score 0):

The below queries can find the CPU and memory for a query.

The dynamic performance views are tricky and can take a while to get used to.  They may contain results from multiple runs and they will age out over time.

```
--1. First run the query, if it hasn't already been run.
select ...

--2. Find the SQL_ID by searching for some unique text in the query:
select sql_id, sql_fulltext from gv$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like '%unique string%';

--3. Find the amount of CPU time used by this query.
--GV$SQL is based on the shared_pool, it may contain the time for multiple runs
--in the "recent past", usually the past few hours or days.
--The data can be flushed with: alter system flush shared_pool;
select cpu_time/1000000 cpu_seconds, gv$sql.*
from gv$sql
where sql_id = 'f6krg7hkt08k2';

--4. The memory and temporary tablespace used by a query.
--This only counts memory and temporary tablespace used for things like sorting and hashing.
--There's no easy way to tell how a query is affecting the buffer cache.
--(Calculating for a parallel query may require different aggregation.)
--GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY also contains temporary samples and will usually only
--have data for the past few hours or days.
select
    max(pga_allocated/1024/1024/1024) max_pga_allocated_gb,
    max(temp_space_allocated/1024/1024/1024) max_temp_space_allocated_gb
from gv$active_session_history
where sql_id = 'f6krg7hkt08k2'
```

Also I recommend you change `'2012-08-01'` to `date '2012-08-01'`.  Without the keyword `date` the query is using a date format that depends on the user's session  settings.  With the `date` keyword the string is now a date literal and conforms to ISO 8601 and will work on any client.

Comment: Most grateful for your help. But i would like to know the following: 1. Am i to run the queries you suggested after running my query in other to determine memory and cpu usage?? 2. How do i get the sql_id in the queries you suggested??  or am i supposed to use what you gave i.e   sql_id = 'f6krg7hkt08k2'??

Comment: @user3432995 See my updated answer for more information.

Comment: Most grateful for you help once again.  I was able to get the CPU time. I would like to know if there is another way to get the CPU usage in percentages.